# How can I separate a function in a string inputted by the user and plot this function?

Tags: javascript, string, function, parsing, math

I am trying to make a program in JavaScript/HTML where the user inputs a string that is a math function such as `cos(x)+3` or `x^2-1` and the the JavaScript program parses this input and plots it using p5.js. I am not looking for a solution to the entire problem, but instead a way to start approaching the problem or an external library that might help.

I've done some research to see how I might solve this but I can't find anything except some Python and Objective-C solutions. What is a JS function/framework that I can use to parse this input into a function?

Comment: This is a little too broad. You need to decide how to parse the string in to a function you can call, which may not be trivial depending on how much math you want to support. Then you can decide what range of `x` you want to plot and call the function at intervals over that range to get the `y` value. [math.js](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html) might be helpful for the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the below snippet. I'm making use of javascript "eval" function where you can literally run arbitary code.

Use of eval should be done judiciously. As you can run literally any arbitary input. Perhaps you can apply stringent input sanitization mechanism etc. This is not a complete solution rather a starting point to build something more complex.

I hope this helps

```js
function doMath(){
  let expr = document.forms[0].mathExpr.value
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = eval(expr);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Math program Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label>Please enter math expression:</label><input type="text" name="mathExpr" value="" />
<input type="button" name="result" value="Result" onclick="doMath();" />
</form>
<h2>Result: <span id="output"></span></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This helps a lot. Just wondering, what is the purpose of the first two lines of the code. Are they just an example of the ```eval()``` function or are they important to the code?

Comment: Yeah they are example. Sorry forgot to delete them :-)

Comment: Ok. So they are just an example.

Comment: Deleted those 2 extra lines.